# Is a Collection better than a LinkedList?

Tags: java, collections

```
Collection list = new LinkedList(); // Good?
LinkedList list = new LinkedList(); // Bad?
```

First variant gives more flexibility, but is that all? Are there any other reasons to prefer it? What about performance?

Comment: Collection is a interface which is implemented by LinkedList. You should always point with an interface at the implementation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are design decisions, and one size usually doesn't fit all. Also the choice of what is used internally for the member variable can (and usually should be) different from what is exposed to the outside world.

At its heart, Java's collections framework does not provide a complete set of interfaces that describe the *performance* characteristics without exposing the implementation details. The one interface that describes performance, [`RandomAccess`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/RandomAccess.html) is a marker interface, and doesn't even extend `Collection` or re-expose the `get(index)` API. So I don't think there is a good answer.

As a rule of thumb, I keep the type as unspecific as possible until I recognize (and document) some characteristic that is important. For example, as soon as I want methods to know that insertion order is retained, I would change from `Collection` to `List`, and document why that restriction is important. Similarly, move from `List` to `LinkedList` if say efficient removal from front becomes important.

When it comes to exposing the collection in public APIs, I always try to start exposing just the few APIs that are expected to get used; for example `add(...)` and `iterator()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Collection list = new LinkedList(); //bad
```

This is bad because, you don't want this reference to refer say an HashSet(as HashSet also implements Collection and so does many other class's in the collection framework).

```
LinkedList list = new LinkedList(); //bad?
```

This is bad because, good practice is to always code to the interface.

```
List list = new LinkedList();//good
```

This is good because point 2 days so.([**Always Program To an Interface**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340623/programming-to-an-interface-how-to-decide-where-its-needed))

Comment: @Aboutblank Array is not a collection and also Map is not a Collection :)

Comment: @PermGenError I didnt understand "because point 2 days so" partm can you re-phrase it or explain?

Comment: @GraphicsToBe check it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/340623/programming-to-an-interface-how-to-decide-where-its-needed

Comment: and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194278/should-you-always-code-to-interfaces-in-java :)

Comment: The first case is not necessarily bad, you should probably explain why.

Comment: @Perception i already said it in my answer, It is bad because, asmany other class's also implement Collection interface in jav acollection framework. you don't want an reference variable referring to a list implementation to refer to an Set implemntation later in the code.

Comment: @PermGenError - yes, but that assumes that you care about list semantics vs collection semantics. In other words, thats a design time decision (aka, its not *always* bad to choose Collection over List).

Comment: @Perception hmm, but it is not generally accepted practice is it ? at least when compared to 3rd approach which is pretty accepted standard. :)

Comment: @Perception Collection and List are equally bad:)

Comment: @zhong.j.yu do you mean programming to an interace is bad ?

Comment: @zhong.j.yu - sorry, I 100% disagree. Maybe you can make a convincing argument but I doubt it.

Comment: program to interfaces _at the API level_, not at the implementation level.

Comment: I am down voting because of this `Collection list = new LinkedList(); //bad` as it's not bad. If all you care about is a `Collection`, then why does it matter if it's a `List`? Why would care if the `Collection ` is a `LinkedList`, `ArrayList`, or `HashSet`?

Comment: @SteveKuo so do you mean to say its good programming practice ??

Comment: It's a good practice to program to the interface that you care about. If all I care about is operating on a `Collection`, and don't need linear indexing (`List`), uniqueness (`Set`), navigability (`NavigableSet`), sorted order (`SortedSet`), then why bother constraining to those interfaces?

Comment: I also don't understand why it's bad to refer to a `HashSet`

Answer (score 2):

Use the most specific type information on non-public objects. They are implementation details, and we want our implementation details as specific and precise as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. If for example java will find and implement more efficient implementation for the List collection, but you already have API that accepts only LinkedList, you won't be able to replace the implementation if you already have clients for this API. If you use interface, you can easily replace the implementation without breaking the APIs.

Answer (score 0):

They're absolutely equivalent.  The only reason to use one over the other is that if you later want to use a function of list that only exists in the class LinkedList, you need to use the second.

Answer (score 0):

My general rule is to only be as specific as you need to be at the time (or will need to be in the near future, within reason).  Granted, this is somewhat subjective.

In your example I would usually declare it as a `List` just because the methods available on `Collection` aren't very powerful, and the distinction between a `List` and another `Collection` (`Map`, `Set`, etc.) is often logically significant.

Also, in Java 1.5+ don't use raw types -- if you don't know the type that your list will contain, at least use `List<?>`.